# SQL server select query with NOLOCK not working

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following query

```
 SELECT *
  FROM T1 with (NOLOCK )
```

Select query can go anywhere as user (I) does that.

And my application script is inserting 1000's of row of data and deleting old one:
All these statement are inside my java code.And the insert is batch insert.

**--I have set autocommit false here**

```
truncate table T1
insert into table T1 values(x,y,z)
truncate table T2
insert into table T2 values(x,y,z)...and other
```

**--I commit transaction here**

But I don't get data from T1 until the truncate and insert is complete. How could it be possible to avoid such situation?

Comment: Please clarify at which point in the `TRUNCATE` / `INSERT` sequence you are executing the `SELECT`.

Comment: @BarryKaye I have edited this might be clear now.

Comment: From my testing inserts do not create the problem but truncates. If you move them before `begin transaction` select returns records inserted so far. I'll try to find an explanation.

Comment: `TRUNCATE` takes a `SCH-M` lock on the table. This is incompatible with the schema stability lock that even a `SELECT` with `NOLOCK` needs.

Comment: @MartinSmith So does that mean I need to use Delete *

Answer (score 1):

You should consider replacing your INSERT INTO statements with [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx). Also consider changing transaction isolation levels before and restore after you run your scripts, such as

```
alter database mydb set READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

or even

```
alter database mydb set READ_UNCOMMITED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

This will effectively allow you to get rid of NOLOCK statements altogether.

Comment: Then dumping the data to a file and importing with BULK INSERT can be a cheap and easy way to speed things up 5-10 times or more.

Comment: Not an option as I can't write to a file on remote server.

Comment: You don't need to write file on remote server in order to use BULK INSERT, you run it locally against remove server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9623/discussion-between-kitex-and-bluesrockaddict)

Answer (score 0):

you wont be able to see the data until all the batch is completed. even though you are doing a read uncommitted select, the data of the insert will only exist on the table when it finishes the insert command

```
truncate table T1
insert into table T1 values(x,y,z)

**data available for dirty read on T1 here **

truncate table T2
insert into table T2 values(x,y,z)...and other
```

you can test what I mean by doing this:

```
truncate table T1
insert into table T1 values(x,y,'My test values')
**read data here**
insert into table T1 values(x,y,z)
```

if you run a dirty read on **read data here** you will be able to see the 'My test values'

Answer (score -1):

> SELECT * FROM T1 (NOLOCK)

Skip "with".